# Windows 7 is crashing

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I've been facing very strange problem on my windows operating system. The problem is whenever I do hibernate, shutdown, restart or lock on my O.S it doesn't perform the required action, and it gets fresh start with the following information:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   9f
  BCP1: 0000000000000003
  BCP2: FFFFFA800389DBB0
  BCP3: FFFFF80000B9C518
  BCP4: FFFFFA8005ADD910
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\072012-16536-01.dmp
  C:\Users\pawan\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-73757-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Could anyone please tell me what's the error log is suggesting, and how can I solve this strange problem?

Comment: when you say it gets a fresh start, do you mean the PC shows the BSOD and then reboots?

Comment: yes, it shows first BSOD and then reboots

Comment: Can you tell us your pc model? Windows 7 64 or 32bit?

Comment: Did you install any driver recently?....Basically, what started this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [KB fix KB975599](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975599)

> Stop error when you put a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 to sleep, into hibernation, or when you restart the computer: `0x9F`

Open [the site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975599) and click on the link View and request hotfix downloads , select the platform (x86 or x64) and type in your email twice and type in the captcha and click request hotfix.

After 1 minute you have an email with the link to download an exe. Use the password which is included inside the email to extract the update.

Referenced from [Microsoft Answers page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/bccode9f-every-time-when-windows-7-comes-back-from/c7490a12-4152-4e98-a14f-1307d64f588b).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the following troubleshooting to fix the problem:

1. Run Windows Updates.
2. Check system BIOS version (update to the latest version if necessary)
3. Update the Chipset, Wireless and Video Card Driver.
4. Run PC Diagnostics with [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) or [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ubcd4win.com/)
5. For the BSOD codes, look them up on: [MSDN Bugs Check Code reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994433.aspx)
6. Perform a clean boot:

Click on "Start" when your Windows 7 loads.
Type "msconfig" on the search bar and hit "Enter".
Go to the "Startup" tab and disable all the applications listed.
Then go to the "Services" tab and check mark the "Hide all Microsoft Service".
Click on "Disable all Services".
Click on Apply and restart the computer.

Test the computer and if no BSOD is shown, start re-enabling one by one each Service and each Startup application until you discover which one is causing the BSOD.

Extra help [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135).

Follow this guide you will find a solution. Remember to test the computer after any change if no BSOD is shown.